# React Native pod install faills

Tags: ios, cocoapods, react-native

I try to install React Native through pods to use it in an existing project. However I get an error during pod installation, which indicates problems with with the contextify package. On the other hand I noticed that I am able to install that package through npm only in sudo mode. Pods don't run in that mode however. Is there anything I can do? Here's the detailed description of the error I get:

```
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/contextify.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make: *** [Release/contextify.node] Error 1

gyp ERR! build error 

gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)

gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)

gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0

gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"

gyp ERR! cwd /Users/marcin/Desktop/soap2/ios-client/Pods/React/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify

gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.32

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3

gyp ERR! not ok 

npm WARN prefer global eslint@0.9.2 should be installed with -g

npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0

npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"

npm ERR! node v0.10.32

npm ERR! npm  v2.9.0

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE



npm ERR! contextify@0.1.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.

npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,

npm ERR! not with npm itself.

npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:

npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild

npm ERR! You can get their info via:

npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify

npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, React packages will try to install npm and it does not have proper rights.Try running "sudo npm install" in /Pods/React directory in your project folder.Manually installing the npm using above command may fix this issue.